# Merging two array of classes

Tags: java, optimization, performance, array

I have this function that should merge two array of classes when `id` of array1 is equal to `id` of array2.

For simplicity I converted one array into an ArrayList so I can remove the occurrence merged into the other one..

I'm looking a way to improve it, also in cpu-time, because the two arrays can have more then 20000rows.
The actual way, should take some time..

```
public Asset[] merge(Asset[] a2, ArrayList<countR> a)
{
        while (a.size()!=0){
            int i=0;
            Boolean b=false;
            while (i<a2.length && b==false)
            {
                if (a.get(0).id.equals(a2[i].id)){
                    a2[i].TotaleRegistrazioni = a.get(0).tot; 
                    b=true;
                }               
                i++;
            }
            a.remove(0);
        }
return a2;
}
```

Comment: Have you done any performance test which shows that this is a performance bottleneck? 20k item isn't so much...

Comment: without looking at the time to scroll the entire array, I only would like to know if there is a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staying with your original code you can change `b` to a simple `break` and you can change the inner `while` to a `for` which is easier to read:

```
public Asset[] merge2(final Asset[] firstArray, final ArrayList<CountR> secondList) {
    while (secondList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
            final CountR countR = secondList.get(0);
            final Asset asset = firstArray[i];
            if (countR.id.equals(asset.id)) {
                asset.TotaleRegistrazioni = countR.tot;
                break;
            }
        }
        secondList.remove(0);
    }
    return firstArray;
}
```

Searching in a `HashMap` should be faster than iterating through the whole array, so I'd do the following:

```
public Asset[] merge3(final Asset[] firstArray, final CountR[] secondArray) {
    final Map<Id, Asset> assetCache = new HashMap<Id, Asset>();
    for (final Asset asset : firstArray) {
        final Id id = asset.getId();
        assetCache.put(id, asset);
    }

    for (final CountR countR : secondArray) {
        final Id countRId = countR.getId();
        final Asset asset = assetCache.get(countRId);
        if (asset != null) {
            // I supposed that it's int
            final int total = countR.getTot();
            asset.setTotaleRegistrazioni(total); 
        }
    }

    return firstArray;
}
```

(I supposed that the `Asset.id` is unique in the array.) In this case you don't have to convert the second parameter to an array (just the first to a map). Maybe it worth playing with the `initialCapacity` and `loadFactor` parameters of the `HashMap` to avoid the [resizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Dynamic_resizing).